# Can I change the default view of tig?

Tags: tig

The "main" view is the default in tig. Is it possible to change this in tigrc? Specifically, I would like the status view as default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Tig version 1.2, there is no way to configure what view is shown at startup. The best workaround at this point is to use a shell alias. For example, `alias ti='tig status'`. See `tig -h` for other options.